# need alternatives to Insert 2nd data row from Insert Trigger on same table

Tags: mysql, triggers

At a high level I am already aware that you can not insert a new row to the same table and that one should consider a SPROC. Here is the use case though. There is a 3rd party web app and this MySQL DB that I have, so I have no control over the application flow. A request has come in to simplify data entry. What I do have control over is the database. The app is like a CRM and has a contacts table and there is a 2nd contact_relationships table where I am putting the trigger on. Basically the contact_relationships needs three fields.  Two contactIDs (INT) from the contact table and a relationship_type varchar(45) like (Spouse, Sibling, External Family and so on).

The goal here is when a new row is added (the TRIGGER) to the contact_relationships table, that we ALSO write a 2nd row to the SAME TABLE that inverts the contactIDs and keeps the relationship_type. This ensures there is also a record relationship established for the other contact from the same single entry. (ideally should be done in the app).

I'm at my whits end over what should be a stupid simple operation. I even tried this creative implementation.

I created a new _temp table

```
        CREATE TABLE `_temp` (
          `id_temp` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `Contact_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
          `Relation_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
          `Relationship_Type` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id_temp`)
```

I have two triggers on the contact_relationships table

```
#1
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `contact_relationships_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `contact_relationships` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
insert into _temp (Contact_id,Relation_id,Relationship_Type) 
    values(NEW.Contact_id,NEW.Relation_id,NEW.Relationship_Type);
END

#2
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `contact_relationships_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `contact_relationships` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    delete from _temp;
END
```

On the _temp table I have this trigger

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `_temp_AFTER_DELETE` AFTER DELETE ON `_temp` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
     #DO Sleep(2);
         # Sleep commented out as it did not work and only delayed the error
    insert into contact_relationships (Relation_id,Contact_id,Relationship_Type) values(OLD.Contact_id,OLD.Relation_id,OLD.Relationship_Type);
END
```

So my thinking here in pseudo code is like this

```
When a row is inserted into the contact_relationships table write the inverted row to a temp table as I can not write it to the **same table from inside the trigger**.

AFTER the triggered inserted row is complete lets delete the row in the temp table so we can create a DELETE trigger on that other table to write the desired row into the contact_relationship.

At this stage I believe the TRIGGER and TRANSACTIONS on the contact_relationships table are DONE 

On the temp Table a trigger and transaction firing AFTER any contact_relationships transactions
```

Results are maddening and always the same albeit internal or external. I have tried creative functions and sprocs all with the same aggravating results.

```
Contact Relationships : Add New

Can't update table 'contact_relationships' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
Query:

insert into `Contact_Relationships` set       `Contact_id`='2', `Relation_id`='3', `Relationship_Type`='Extended Family'
```

I'm completely brain dead on how I may accomplish this - anyone have a way to pull this off?

Answer (score 0):

dsoden.

What I would do is:

**Inside the trigger definition**, you can get the *"inserted_id"* of the relationship that was inserted ( You can get it with**LAST_INSERT_ID()** ).

Once you have it, you can SELECT from that record into temp variables:

```
SELECT `Contact_id`,`Relation_id`,`Relationship_Type` INTO @cont_id, @rel_id, @rel_type
FROM contact_relationships 
WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

And then do the Insert of the new relationship in the reverse order, with the same relationship type:

```
INSERT INTO contact_relationships (`Contact_id`,`Relation_id`,`Relationship_Type`) VALUES ( @rel_id, @cont_id, @rel_type);
```

If that's what you're aiming for..

Something like:

When a relationship between Anne and John as Siblings is inserted,
insert the John,Anne,Siblings relationship as well

Comment: thanks for the help francovici - you taught me some new tricks so helpful there. I however think I did not implement this correctly. I had to modify the where slightly to match the table WHERE Contact_Relationship_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

the problem still remains the same.

I tried adding both to the BEFORE INSERT then AFTER INSERT and finally split them between both all results = "Can't update table 'contact_relationships' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger."